# Can Read cookie and use in mysql SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$_SESSION["signed"]=true;
setcookie("cookie", $username);
$sql1="SELECT DR_id from `doctor` WHERE $_cookie['username']='$username'" ;
```

Table doctor

```
==========
DR_id|| DR_email      ||
01   || xyz@email.com ||
```

Can I get the id Through Cookie

Comment: You need to use `$_COOKIE`, not `$_cookie`. PHP variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: $_cookie['username'] is the column name?

Comment: Yes this is the column name of DR_email

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should be a column name like `WHERE DR_email='{$_COOKIE['username]}'`

Answer (score 0):

PHP keywords are case sensitive.

```
$_SESSION["signed"]=true;
setcookie("cookie", $username);
$sql1="SELECT DR_id from `doctor` WHERE DR_email ='$_COOKIE['cookie']'" ;
```